# Batch - Script ping multiple ip

Tags: batch-file, ping

I want to make a script to ping many IP addresses. But I don't want to use errorlevel.

I want to ping each IP address 5 times, and display the result:

- If 5 packets lost I want to display an echo %ip - DOWN
- If 3 packets lost I want to display an echo %ip - 3 lost
- etc...

So I want get back "lost packets" in a variable from this line :

"packets: sent = 4, received = 4, **lost = 0** (0% loss)

This is my code but this doesn't work.

```
echo off 

set perte=0 
set servers=servers.txt 

for /f %%i in (%servers%) do call :testping %%i 
goto:eof

:testping 
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims==" %%a IN (' ping -n 5 %1 ^|find "lost"') 
DO (set perte=%%b) 

if %perte%==1 echo %1 lost 1 ping
if %perte%==2 echo %1 lost 2 ping
if %perte%==3 echo %1 lost 3 ping
if %perte%==4 echo %1 lost 4 ping
if %perte%==5 echo %1 DOWN
if %perte%==0 echo %1 UP
goto:eof
```

Comment: `call ::testping %%i ` - why do you have double colon here?

Comment: And if you use "tokens=3", using G as your for loop variable, you get %%G %%H and %%I, so %%p ?

Comment: call ::testping %%i - why do you have double colon here? –  npocmaka 4 mins ago --> because is the rule for call a Function for Batch

Comment: For MC ND ok thank you I have test but doesn't work . I still search

Comment: The double colon works, but it isn't the normal syntax. And you changed `%%G` to `%%a`, so you get now `%%a`, `%%b` and `%%c`,  but again no `%%p`

Comment: Did you tried to add an `echo '%%a'  # '%%b' # '%%c'` into the loop?

Comment: Btw it will fail at least when all ip's tested, as it will run without any ip into `:testping`, there should be one more `goto :eof`

Comment: Why not use `find /c` in the for loop to search and count for the lost packet lines and directly get the correct value in loop variable?

Comment: @jeb: Yes I tried to add echo but the windows closes automatically. I add goto:eof . @ MC ND : I search "find /c" I find this "Displays the count of lines containing the string." but I just want get back lost packets  in a variable from this line " packets: sent = 4, received = 4, lost = 0 (0% loss) " . So I don't need find /c , I guess.

Comment: Your right. My pc is in spanish and i misinterpreted what you were reading.

Comment: On my windows 7 machine in the line you seek all the words are capitalized so you need to use the /I switch; the /c doesn't help because there is only one line with the word Lost.

Answer (score 1):

The tokens, delims and find command are changed.

```
@echo off 

set perte=0 
set servers=servers.txt 

for /f %%i in (%servers%) do call :testping %%i 
goto:eof

:testping 
FOR /f "tokens=7 delims== " %%a IN (' ping -n 5 %1 ^|find /i "lost"') DO (set perte=%%a) 

if %perte%==1 echo %1 lost 1 ping
if %perte%==2 echo %1 lost 2 ping
if %perte%==3 echo %1 lost 3 ping
if %perte%==4 echo %1 lost 4 ping
if %perte%==5 echo %1 DOWN
if %perte%==0 echo %1 UP
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost done. Try

```
@echo off 

    setlocal enableextensions 

    set servers=servers.txt

    for /f %%i in (%servers%) do call :testping %%i

    endlocal
    exit /b

:testping 
    rem
    rem How/Why delims are defined as =,(
    rem Packets: Sent = 5, Received = 5, Lost = 0 (0% loss), 
    rem ..............^..^..........^..^......^...^.........
    rem token: 1       2  3          4  5      6   7
    rem
    FOR /f "tokens=6 delims==,(" %%a IN (' ping -n 5 %1 ^| find /i "lost" ') do (
        if %%a EQU 0 (
            echo %1 UP
        ) else if %%a EQU 5 (
            echo %1 DOWN
        ) else (
            echo %1 lost %%a ping
        )
    )
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you very much you too. As I write up ,I have understood my mistake ( my code is good now )